# Inject local HTML file into webpage via Chrome Extension using iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I have a HTML file that I want to inject next to each result of a Google search result page from a Chrome extension.

I was wondering if I could use an iframe to load the HTML file?

This is instead of my current implementation that uses `insertAdjacentHTML()` in my Content Script and a horrible long string of HTML and inline CSS. Would much prefer to have a separate HTML file with its own CSS that I can just insert instead.

I tried:

```
chosenElements[i].insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `<iframe src="/inject.html"></iframe>`);
```

but just get an iframe with a 404 page because it is looking in the 'https://www.google.com/index.html' directory rather than where the file sits.

The inject.html file is in the same place as the index.html file in my build folder for the extension. How do I access it? Can I access it?

Comment: Declare it in [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) and use chrome.runtime.getURL as shown in the documentation.

Comment: That worked thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with

```
src="inject.html"
```

instead of

`src="/inject.html"`

Comment: I have yes, get the same console error message: 'GET https://www.google.com/inject.html 404'

Answer (score 0):

I'm 5 years late, but in case anybody else ever runs into this issue, you need to use the [browser runtime module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime) if you want to refer to files in your project directory. Something like this should work:

```js
const htmlURL = chrome.runtime.getURL('index.html');
iframe.src = htmlURL
```